# How to use the @WebInitParam that's nested in the @WebServlet annotation in Scala?

Tags: scala, servlets, java-ee-6

I'm playing around with Scala and servlets and I'm trying to use the JEE6 annotations to configure servlets written in Scala. I'm running into a issue with nested annotations. The java code would look something like:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ExampleServlet", urlPatterns = {"/example"},
initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="param1", value="value1"), 
              @WebInitParam(name="param2", value="value2")}
)
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```

the scala code I'm trying is like:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ExampleServlet", urlPatterns = Array("/example"), 
initParams = Array(@WebInitParam(name="param1", value="value1", 
                   @WebInitParam(name="param2", value="value2")))
class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```

but when I try to compile it I get the following:

> [ERROR] /Users/brian/workspace/dsg-scalatra/src/main/scala/org/mbari/dsg/RotatorServlet.scala:15: error: illegal start of simple expression
>
> [INFO]         initParams = Array( @WebInitParam(name="imageDirectory", value="/assets/images/rotator")) )

with the error pointing to the @WebInitParam annotation.

**Any suggestions on how to use the @WebInitParam that's nested in the @WebServlet annotation in Scala?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `new` keyword to instantiate any annotations inside of another annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ExampleServlet", urlPatterns = Array("/example"), 
            initParams = Array(new WebInitParam(name="param1", value="value1"), 
                               new WebInitParam(name="param2", value="value2")))
class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```